# Merging animations on different armatures with different edit mode transforms

Tags: animation, armature

I have two different animations on two armatures that have similar bone hierarchy but different edit mode transforms..

I want to bring those two animations into one armature. But when I copy and paste the data on dope sheets, I get deformed animation..

I think this is because of the different edit mode transforms..

Is there anyway around this??

Comment: what do you call "different edit mode transforms"?

Comment: They have different poses in edit mode

Comment: Yes so the second armature will copy the movement of the first one, for example if a bone1 of armature 1 rotates 30° on X axis, then bone 1 of armature 2 will also rotate 30° on X axis, but of course as the rest pose of each armature is not the same it won't give the same result

Comment: Ya so is there anyway to merge them?

Comment: I guess if you want the animations to fit your new armature you need to duplicate them and change them until they do